# Grouping and counting records by their associated record in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

```
class JobPosition < AR
  belongs_to :recruiter, class_name: 'User'
end

class User < AR
  # first_name, last_name
end
```

Recruiters (or rather Users) can be attached to many job positions. I want to get a count of how many requisitions each recruiter is assigned to. This is easy via

```
JobPosition.group(:recruiter_id).count
```

which returns the count for each recruiter id.

```
{
  1 => 3,
  2 => 5
}
```

However I dont want the recruiter id, but instead the recruiters full name like so

```
{
  "Peter Henry" => 3,
  "Hugh Kavener" => 5
}
```

I don't have a full_name column on the users table but do have first_name and last_name.

How do I achieve this using **PG and ActiveRecord**. I'd prefer not to resort to manipulating active record objects in memory.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it by writing a little extra SQL, I believe the following syntax should work for postgresql:

```
JobPosition.joins(:recruiters).group("user.first_name || ' ' || user.last_name").count
```